# alertDialog.getButton() method gives null pointer exception android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Iam planing to give create 3 buttons with layout_weight=1, not interested in custom dialog.So I have written below code.It is not working.Always yes button gives me null.
Whats wrong in this code?

```
  AlertDialog dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon);
            dialog.setTitle("title");
            dialog.setMessage("Message");
            dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                                }
            });
            Button yesButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Log.w("Button",""+yesButton);//here getting null
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
            yesButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            dialog.show();
```

Regards,
Android developer.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Take a look here for the answer : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6360

As it says in comment #4 you must call `show()` on your dialog before you can access the buttons, they are not available beforehand. For an automatic solution on how to modify the buttons as soon as they are ready see [Mickeys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14601488/2135787)

Comment: Still problem persist.No Use of that link.

Comment: Please read the comment #4,  use dialog.show(); before using getButton()

Answer (score 76):

This works for me :

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //do smthng
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do snthn
                    }
                }).create();

        alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {                    //
                Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog)
                        .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                positiveButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_default_holo_dark));

                Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog)
                        .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                positiveButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_default_holo_dark));
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
```

only in this order, call `alertDialog.setOnShowListener` after `create()`

Comment: setOnShowListener is API 8+

Answer (score 6):

Thanks wieux. But for new developers understanding purpose I am re-writing code below

```
AlertDialog dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();             
dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon);             
dialog.setTitle("title");            
dialog.setMessage("Message");             
dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                 
    @Override                 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {                                                
    }             
}); 
dialog.show(); 
Button yesButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);             
Log.w("Button",""+yesButton); //here getting null             
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);             
yesButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is useful Kotlin extensions functions to achieve what you want with an automatic solution :

```kotlin
import android.content.DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE
import android.content.DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog

fun AlertDialog.onPositiveButtonClick(action: () -> Unit) {
    onButtonClick(BUTTON_POSITIVE, action)
}

fun AlertDialog.onNegativeButtonClick(action: () -> Unit) {
    onButtonClick(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, action)
}

fun AlertDialog.onButtonClick(whichButton: Int, action: () -> Unit) {
    fun onButtonClick() = getButton(whichButton).setOnClickListener { action() }

    if (isShowing) {
        onButtonClick()
    } else {
        setOnShowListener {
            onButtonClick()
        }
    }
}
```

How to use :

```kotlin
alertDialog.onPositiveButtonClick { /* DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE */ }
```