# EdiText crash with button.setEnabled()

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I am trying to make an EditText with a listener that checks the length of the text entered. If the EditText is not empty then the button should be enabled, otherwise it is empty must be disabled. To do this I wrote this code.

```
        final EditText editText = new EditText(context);
        builder.setView(editText);
        builder.setTitle("TItle");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {



            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", null);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
              {
                  AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                  dialog.show();
                  String text = editText.getText().toString();

                  if(text.trim().length()>0) {
                     button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                     button.setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  else {
                     button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                     button.setEnabled(false);
                  }
              }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
           });
```

Just write something in EditText crashes with a NullPointerException here:                      button.setEnabled(false);

Why? how can i solve?

Comment: Have you initialized `button`? It may be `null`

Comment: Is isn't initialized with dialogo.getButton etc. ?

Comment: that only happens in the `if` case. Not in the `else` case. Look at my answer below. Should resolve it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Seems like `dialogo.getButton()` is returning `null` in your case. I looked up, there is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604025/alertdialog-getbutton-method-gives-null-pointer-exception-android) related.

Basically you need `dialogo.show()` before you call `getButton()`. So update your code as:

```
builder.setNegativeButton("No", null);
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {

        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        ...
        ...
        button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        if(button != null) {    
            if(text.trim().length()>0) {
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else {
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
...
```

**Old Answer**

Change your `else` to following:

```
...
...
else {
   button = dialogo.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
   button.setEnabled(false);
}
...
...
```

Comment: Crash the same in the IF when i insert text. Always NullPointerException here:                   button.setEnabled(false);

Comment: post your updated code.. also.. could you debug and check if `dialogo.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);` returns null?

Comment: If i remove button.setEnabled(false) when i insert text don't crash

Comment: Are you talking about the `else` case? i dont see any other `setEnabled(false)`? See everyone is giving the same answer.. are you not giving us some info?

Comment: @GiovanniMariotti please see updated answer.. my question is why you never call `dialog.show()` you need that before `getButton`

Comment: Crash again at dialogo.show() with illegalstatexception the specified child already has a parent you must call removeView().. i update mu question with full code

Comment: @GiovanniMariotti updated my answer again. I hope it resolves the problem now. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Initially when you click on the the edit text, the addTextChangedListener will be fired and since you have not entered and text `text.trim().length()=0` so the control goes to the else block.

In your else block, you are not initializing the the button, hence the NPE.

You have write the following line in else block too

```
button = dialogo.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
```