# Android alert dialog button background

Tags: dialog, alert

In Android Alert Dialog : dialog.getButton is not available 
How to change the background of the Positive button in laert dialog

Answer (score 8):

You need to write it after 
dialog.show();

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewApplication.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setNegativeButton("Yes",new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).
       setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3399ff"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been addressed here before, IRC.

Check these answers posted earlier on a similar issue:

[Android Button modify Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604025/alertdialog-getbutton-method-gives-null-pointer-exception-android)

Good links and answers there.

Comment: I have tried that which is mentioned in your given link but i am not able to call the method .getButton() i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

First off, the

```
'
       `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`'
```

listener — must not be NULL .

Second make sure you imported the correct Android classes, there are a lot of them, and some are version specific.
For example:

`import android.content.Context;
      import android.database.ContentObserver;
      import android.database.Cursor;
      import android.database.DataSetObserver;
      import android.os.Handler;
      import android.util.Log;`

Here is a quick and dirty sample of code in Java that illustrates the use of some special Android imports you need for an application. Remember Android uses many special classes and objects all its own.

`final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)...create();
         //final Button b1 = d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
       editName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() //
        {
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable ed) {
          Button b1 = d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE); 
           //comment out sections that may or may not work //
          b1.setEnabled(ed.length() > 0);`

```
    private static final class  [More ...] ButtonHandler extends Handler {
      // Button clicks have Message.what as the BUTTON{1,2,3} constant//
      private static final int MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG = 1;
      private WeakReference<DialogInterface> mDialog;
      public void //  whatever classes you want // 
      ButtonHandler(DialogInterface dialog) {
         mDialog = new WeakReference<DialogInterface>(dialog);
     }
```

Use override to set replacement buttons or new button messages in a new section. It is one way to use the same button positioning for a new function. For example:

```
     @Override
        public void  [More ...] 
           handleMessage(Message msg) {
           switch (msg.what) {
             case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
             case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
             case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:

                 ((DialogInterface.OnClickListener)  
                 msg.obj).onClick(mDialog.get(), msg.what);
                 break;
             case MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG:
               ((DialogInterface) msg.obj).dismiss();

          }
```

Hope this helps answer your question.

Code illustrated for illustration only, it is not the actual code, you need to write your own.

As an additional note: If you are using eclipse or other GUI interface, it tends to add a lot of additional and unnecessary code. Try coding on a text editor like Notepad++ and you will find it to be cleaner and smoother.

Answer (score 0):

U try to Custom Alert dialog

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/ll_head"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="30dp"
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>     android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
>     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/ll_head"
>     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>     android:background="@color/colorAccent"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
>     android:id="@+id/button" />
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>     android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
>     android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="53dp" /> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Dialog alertDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```