# Content Description of Alert Dialog buttons

Tags: android, automation, appium

I'm displaying an AlertDialog as follows:

```
private void showAlertDialog(String message){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
        .show();
}
```

I would like to run automation tests which relay on `android:contentDescription` to read values.

Is it possible to add/get this parameter from Positive and Negative Button of built-in Alert Dialog?

Comment: You can set it by `alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setContentDescription("positive");`.

Comment: @ADM charming! This should be an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already answered in comment, Just to Close the question with an accepted answer...

You can get Dialog's action Button Using `#alertDialog.getButton()` ... In this particular case You can use :-

```
alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setContentDescription("positive");
alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setContentDescription("negative");
```

Comment: Note: should use this after alertDialog.show() or else you will get an NPE

Comment: Yeah i forget to add that .. Here is [Full reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604025/alertdialog-getbutton-method-gives-null-pointer-exception-android).

Answer (score 1):

Checking file `alert_dialog.xml` at `ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-28/data/res/layout`, I can see the buttons from a **REGULAR/STANDARD**  `AlertDialog` is defined as follow:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ... />
<Button android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ... />
<Button android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ... />
```

Then, you can search those views and get their content as follows:

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @ADM in the comments, you can easily run the code below:

> You can set it by `alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setContentDescription("positive");`

Easier and simple.. And you don't need to rely on the View ID.. very good (and best) solution!