# AlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE) returns null despite dialog having a positive button

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class that extends the AppCompatDialogFragment. I want it to create a popup where the user can input their password. But I get this error every time I run the app.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Here is my code for the class onCreateDialog method:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    //The popup
    val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    val mFlater = activity?.layoutInflater
    val mView =mFlater?.inflate(R.layout.activity_get_password, null)

    //Get the EditText
    val getPassword: EditText = mView!!.findViewById(R.id.getPassword)

    mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok"){ _, _ ->}

    //Set the view
    mBuilder.setView(mView)

    //Set the AlertDialog
    val alertDialog = mBuilder.create().apply {
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    }

    //Set the clicklistener for the
    alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener {
        val password = getPassword.text.toString()
        if(password == db?.getPassword()) {
            //Send the password
            interfaces?.getPassword(password)

            //Close the alert dialog
            alertDialog.dismiss()
        } else //Wrong password?
            Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid Password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    return alertDialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call `show()` before `getButton()`. If you want automatically set ClickListener callback when dialog is shown, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14601488/6686126).

---

You need to know about [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types). When calling java method in kotlin, it will return platform type unless you use @NotNull or @Nullable annotations.

For example, `alertDialog.getButton()` returns **platform type**(null).
Kotlin behaves like non-null, whether the return value is null or non-null, because it is platform type.
**So even if null is returned, `null.setOnClickListener()` is called.**

Comment: Why is it returning `null`?  The fact that it *can* return null doesn't explain why it _does_.

Comment: Thanks @RyanM. I misunderstood it as just a platform type issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause:** From [AlertDialog](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java) source code:

```
/**
 * Gets one of the buttons used in the dialog. Returns null if the specified
 * button does not exist or the dialog has not yet been fully created (for
 * example, via {@link #show()} or {@link #create()}).
 *
 * @param whichButton The identifier of the button that should be returned.
 *                    For example, this can be
 *                    {@link DialogInterface#BUTTON_POSITIVE}.
 * @return The button from the dialog, or null if a button does not exist.
 */
public Button getButton(int whichButton) {
    return mAlert.getButton(whichButton);
}
```

In your case, the `getButton()` method return `null` because the dialog has not been fully created via [show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#show()) or [create()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#create()).

**Solution:** Calling one of these two methods before calling the `getButton()` method to make sure the dialog has been fully created.

```
// Set the AlertDialog
val alertDialog = mBuilder.create().apply {
    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
}

// Calling show or create method here
alertDialog.show(); // or alertDialog.create();

// Set the clicklistener for the
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener {
    val password = getPassword.text.toString()
    if (password == db?.getPassword()) {
        //Send the password
        interfaces?.getPassword(password)

        //Close the alert dialog
        alertDialog.dismiss()
    } else { //Wrong password?
        Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid Password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```